# Having a static DNS hostname

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp

I have a real-time application running on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ who generate a (very big) logs file. To allow non-technical people to download it, I create a Desktop application coded with Electron (NodeJs). 
The idea is to list all available IP addresses of the network with theirs hostname to allow the non-technical guys to select the correct one and automatically copy (through SFTP) the log file on their PC.
The SFTP code works fine (thanks to the module ssh2 in nodejs), however, I can identify as I would like my Raspberry. They correctly get IP address from the DHCP server, but I can't find a way to get their hostname.
Below the output from my code who list of available system on the network:

```
192.168.5.61  // err:  { Error: getnameinfo ENOTFOUND 192.168.5.61
    at GetNameInfoReqWrap.onlookupservice [as oncomplete] (dns.js:159:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getnameinfo',
  hostname: '192.168.5.61' }
192.168.5.61  //  undefined  //  undefined
192.168.5.65  //  USER-PC  //  ssh
192.168.5.62  //  KM59CD4F  //  ssh
192.168.5.100  //  server.blabla.com.au  //  ssh
```

As you can see, all systems send back a valid hostname, except for mine who raised an error. My question is, **who can I configure on my Raspberry to send back a valid hostname ?**
I tried to play with dhcpd.conf, dnsmasq.conf and hosts. The perfect result will be the same than '192.168.5.65  //  USER-PC  //  ssh', with USER-PC becoming my system hostname.

Nota: When I put a static IP address in /etc/hosts, my code detect it and send me back the correct hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scan doesn't query the systems themselves. It queries the internal DNS server on your router, which collects hostnames that were provided as part of DHCP lease request.

If the Raspberry Pi uses DHCP to get its IP address, make sure the DHCP client is configured to send the 'hostname' lease option (12). Some routers might also accept the 'fqdn' option (81).

- For dhcpcd, add the option `hostname` to the configuration file.
- For dhclient, add the option `send host-name = gethostname();` to the configuration file. (You can also specify a custom name using `send host-name = "foo";`.)
- For NetworkManager, enable `ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname` in the connection profile. (Some versions *may* need `ipv4.dhcp-hostname` to be manually set to the hostname you want.)
- For systemd-network, make sure the [DHCP] section has `SendHostname=` enabled (default) and `Anonymize=` disabled (also default).

If the Raspberry Pi uses static IP configuration, you'll also need to add a static DNS entry to the router itself. (It should be enough to map name → address, and the router will add the reverse mapping.)

Comment: I'm using dhcpcd and I already have the 'hostname' option enabled. As you advised, I try to setup dhclient, but same issue. About my code, it's using [dns module](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookupservice_address_port_callback) from NodeJs. Maybe my mistake comes from the code  ? Also, I double-check the DHCP hostname send by my Raspberry and it's correct, I can see my Raspberry's hostname  on my company's DHCP server.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: Nope, to be honest, I don't know what is it.

Comment: Is _the company_ using Active Directory? What software is used for your DNS server?

Comment: No idea, I don't have access to the network configuration and the guys who manage it is out for 2 weeks haha ... #ironic. What I know is, they have Windows server and only one local network pretty simple (192.168.5.1/24). But is shouldn't mater, isn't it ? When i add manually the IP adress gave by the company's DHCP server in /etc/hosts with an host name, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error was coming from my company's DHCP server. It is a (very) old version of Windows Server (2003), I did the same test on a more recent version and it work as expect.